# How Do I copy few specific type of files from source to destination directory using cmake commands?

Tags: cmake

I am completely new to Cmake. My Query might be very simple for you

I want to copy few files from source directory to destination Directory. below is my Source directory structure

```
SourceDir\tem1.txt
SourceDir\tem1.log
SourceDir\tem1.xml
SourceDir\tem1.js
SourceDir\tem3.xml
```

SourceDir has another directory Say ChildDir ; below is the structure

```
SourceDir\ChildDir\tem1.ts
SourceDir\ChildDir\tem4.log
SourceDir\ChildDir\tem5.xml
SourceDir\ChildDir\tem6.js
SourceDir\ChildDir\tem7.xml
```

I want to copy only .xml and .js file in my destination directory. The output should be as shown below

```
DestinationDir/tem1.xml
DestinationDir/tem1.js
DestinationDir/tem3.xml
DestinationDir/tem5.xml
DestinationDir/tem6.js
DestinationDir/tem7.xml
```

below is my incomplete codesnipet

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)

project(copyFiles)
add_custom_target(temp)

add_custom_command( TARGET temp
                      PRE_BUILD
                      ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                      COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SourceDir
 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DestinationDir)
```

Is there any way to update this code snippet to get my work done? or do let me know if there is any other better solution.
thanks in advance

Comment: In what context do you need to move the files? Is it during testing or for every build of the main target or perhaps just an optional target (like compiling documentation)?

Comment: The file should be copied after every build, these files are generated post build and need to be copied to a distribution directory at a specific path

Answer (score 1):

**First step : match all .js and .xml files**

You can use the [`file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/file.html?highlight=file#filesystem) with GLOB_RECURSE :

```
file (GLOB_RECURSE 
      MY_FILES
      "SourceDir/*.js"
      "SourceDir/*.xml"
)
```

The GLOB_RECURSE will match all file in the folder and all its subfolders.

Now `MY_FILES` variable have all your .xml and .js files.

**Second step : copy files**

Now MY_FILES variable is a list. Definition of a list in CMAKE :

> NOTES: A list in cmake is a ; separated group of strings. To create a list the set command can be used. For example, set(var a b c d e) creates a list with a;b;c;d;e, and set(var “a b c d e”) creates a string or a list with one item in it. (Note macro arguments are not variables, and therefore cannot be used in LIST commands.)

Now you have two choices to copy.

*At CMake time :*

You can use [`file(COPY)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/file.html?highlight=file#copy) , this will copy file when you do `cmake` :

```
file(COPY ${MY_FILES} DESINATION "DestinationDir/")
```

*At make time :*

That's the method you use currently. But you need to iterate on the list of `MY_FILES`. In order to do this you need to use the [`foreach()` loop](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/foreach.html?highlight=foreach). The code will be something like :

```
foreach(MY_FILE ${MY_FILES})
    add_custom_command( TARGET temp
                        PRE_BUILD
                        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                        COPY ${MY_FILE}
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DestinationDir
    )
endforeach()
```

Comment: I tried with 
file(COPY ${MY_FILES} DESINATION "DestinationDir/")
it copied all the files in DestinationDir directory. However, I was expecting that it will copy the subdirectory as well.

Comment: Yes try out with your syntax `add_custom_command()` the `file()` syntax do not copy the directories

Comment: Or you can use `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${directory})` to create the directory before copy your files.